# NullPointerException when passing values from an activity to another

Tags: android, bluetooth, nullpointerexception

Why is there a `NullPointerException` error when I try to pass the data from an activity and write it to OutputStream to send to a remote Bluetooth device?

In activity A:

```
BluetoothConnection mSendMessage = new BluetoothConnection();
mSendMessage.send();
```

In BluetoothConnection:

```
public ConnectedThread mConnectedThread;

public synchronized void ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket){
    ConnectedThread mConnectedThread = new ConnectedThread(socket);
    mConnectedThread.start();
}

public void send() throws IOException{                  
    byte[] byteString = (1 + " ").getBytes();
    mConnectedThread.write(byteString);
}
```

In ConnectedThread:

```
public void run(){
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024]; 
    int bytes;      

    while (true) {
      try {
          bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);
      } catch (IOException e) {
    break;
    }
  }
}

public void write (byte[] buffer){
try{
     mmOutStream.write(buffer);          
}catch(IOException e){
}
}
```

The `NullPointerException` occurred at the line "mSendMessage.send()" in activity A. The bluetooth connection between the phone and device is established already. mmOutStream and mmInStream are defined as

```
mmInStream = socket.getInputStream();
mmOutStream = socket.getOutputStream();
```

Additional question: If nothing is sent from the remote Bluetooth Device to the phone, does the while(true) loop blocks the whole code such that write() method is never called? Could it be possible?

Comment: is mConnectedThread initialized in the default constructor of BluetoothConnection?

Comment: @shannon please post your logcat

Comment: @rajshree I actually did this: try{
  mSendMessage.send();
   
  }catch(IOException e){
   System.out.println("IOException at send");
  }catch(NullPointerException e){
   System.out.println("NullPointerException at send()"); 
  }

Comment: @Srikanth Yes I tried initialising mConnectedThread but still get Null Pointer Exception.

Comment: Hi could it be possible that the program is blocked at the while(true) loop and write() is never called?

Answer (score 4):

As I can see you're doing a tiny mistake, Null Pointer Exception only comes when a variable does not initialize before use. You need to change your code a little as following :

```
public synchronized void ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket){
    mConnectedThread = new ConnectedThread(socket);
    mConnectedThread.start();
}
```

The problem was, you have made local instance of ConnectedThread class which does not contain any data to send. Just replace "ConnectedThread()" function with the above. Hope you can understand now.

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer, I initialised mConnectedThread as public ConnectedThread mConnectedThread; and replaced the ConnectedThread() function with the above. However, it still gives Null Pointer Exception.

Comment: I actually did this: try{ mSendMessage.send(); }catch(IOException e){ System.out.println("IOException at send"); }catch(NullPointerException e){ System.out.println("NullPointerException at send()");  } so there was no error in logcat, but it printed out the above.

Comment: tell me one thing where does "ConnectedThread(socket)" function get called ?

Comment: It gets called inside ConnectThread.java which extends Thread and connects to the remote bluetooth device. Like this:   BluetoothConnection mConnectedThread = new BluetoothConnection();
mConnectedThread.ConnectedThread(mmSocket);

Comment: that is what I am asking, where you have called this ? I can not see in your code , it should be called before calling send() function

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46725/discussion-between-shannon-and-thelittlenaruto)